# display variable smarty into {php} tag

Tags: php, templates, variables, smarty

i have problem with display variable {$mirror.name} in template smarty (download.tpl)

After used {php} tag like these:

```
<a href="{php} linklokurl('{$mirror.name}',10,1,3); {/php}">download</a>
```

Does not display variable، How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty with smarty but for your purposes you should really be using smarty how its supposed to be

So in your php, something like...

```
$mirrorUrl= linklokurl('$mirrorName',10,1,3); // I assume this is some php method you have
$smarty->assign('mirrorUrl' , $mirrorUrl);
$smarty->display('download.tpl');
```

And in your download.tpl it should just be

```
<a href="{$mirrorUrl}">download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you

This is download.php how i can fix it

`$smarty->assign('title', Download." ".$file['file_dlurl']." ".$c['name']."".$file['file_longdesc']);`

`$mirrors = unserialize($file['file_mirrors']);`

`if (!is_array($mirrors)) { exit(); }`

`$smarty->assign('mirrors', $mirrors);`

`$smarty->assign('file', $file);`